# Hadoop jobs.setJar does not working for jars on HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to solve an issue when a Hadoop app throws **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**:

```
WARN mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Using the distribution Faunus job jar: ../lib/faunus-0.4.4-hadoop2-job.jar
INFO mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Compiled to 1 MapReduce job(s)
INFO mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Executing job 1 out of 1: VerticesMap.Map > CountMapReduce.Map > CountMapReduce.Reduce
INFO mapreduce.FaunusCompiler: Job data location: output/job-0
INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at yuriys-bigdata3/172.31.8.161:8032
WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner
INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1402963354379_0016
INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1402963354379_0016
INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://local-bigdata3:8088/proxy/application_1402963354379_0016/
INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1402963354379_0016
INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1402963354379_0016 running in uber mode : false
INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1402963354379_0016_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED     

 Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.DefaultVertexQuery
         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
         at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
         at com.thinkaurelius.faunus.formats.graphson.GraphSONInputFormat.setConf(GraphSONInputFormat.java:39)
         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
         at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:726)
         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1557)
         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
```

The app does create a "fat" jar file, where all the dependency jars (including the one that contains the not found class) are included under the lib node
The app does set the Job.setJar on this fat jar file.

The code does not do anything strange:

```
        job.setJar(hadoopFileJar);
         ...
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Besides, I looked up the configuration in the yarn-site.xml and verified that a job dir under yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs does contain that jar (it is renamed to job.jar though) and also that lib directory with extracted jars in them.  
i.e. the jar that contains the missing class is there. Yarn/MR recreates this dir with all these required files after each job schedule, so the files do get transferred there.

I've discovered so far, is that the classpath environment variable on the java worker processes that execute the failing code is set as

> C:\hdp\data\hadoop\local\usercache\user\appcache\application_1402963354379_0013\container_1402963354379_0013_02_000001\classpath-3824944728798396318.jar

and this jar just contains a manifest.mf That manifest contains paths to the directory with the "fat.jar" file and its directories (original formatting saved):

```
file:/c:/hdp/data/hadoop/loc al/usercache/user/appcache/application_1402963354379_0013/container
_1402963354379_0013_02_000001/job.jar/job.jar file:/c:/hdp/data/hadoo p/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1402963354379_0013/cont ainer_1402963354379_0013_02_000001/job.jar/classes/ file:/c:/hdp/data /hadoop/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1402963354379_001 3/container_1402963354379_0013_02_000001/jobSubmitDir/job.splitmetain fo file:/c:/hdp/data/hadoop/local/usercache/user/appcache/applicati on_1402963354379_0013/container_1402963354379_0013_02_000001/jobSubmi tDir/job.split file:/c:/hdp/data/hadoop/local/usercache/user/appcac he/application_1402963354379_0013/container_1402963354379_0013_02_000 001/job.xml file:/c:/hdp/data/hadoop/local/usercache/user/appcache/ application_1402963354379_0013/container_1402963354379_0013_02_000001 /job.jar/
```

However, this path does not explicitly adds the jars in the directories, i.e. the directory from the above manifest

> file:/c:/hdp/data/hadoop/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1402963354379_0013/container_1402963354379_0013_02_000001/job.jar/

does contain the jar file with the class that is not being found by yarn (as this directory contains all the jars from the "fat" jar lib section), but for JAVA world this kind of setting of classpath seems incorrect – this directory was supposed to be included with star*, 
e.g:

> file:/c:/hdp/data/hadoop/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1402963354379_0013/container_1402963354379_0013_02_000001/job.jar/*

What I am doing wrong with passing dependencies to Yarn? 
Could cluster configuration be an issue or possibly this is a bug on my Hadoop distro (HDP 2.1, Windows x64)?

Comment: See if [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/1pwvtfQ2myY) helps

Comment: No, that linked question does not really have a provided solution

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?